# Type conversion to 'short unsigned int' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]

Tags: c

I don't understand why compiler (GCC) throws  [-Wconversion] warnings at this lines (the code works perfect).

```
 uint16_t ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR crc(uint8_t data, uint16_t crc)
    {
        int i = 8;

        crc = crc ^ (uint16_t)data << 8; // <-- here

        do
        {
            if (crc & 0x8000)
                crc = crc << 1 ^ 0x1021; // <-- here
            else
                crc = crc << 1; // <-- and here
        } while (--i);

        return crc;
    }
```

All operands are uint16_t so why complain?

If constants are evaluated to int, how can I get rid of warnings (not disabling them).

I tried also with no luck

```
crc = crc ^ (uint16_t)data << 8UL;
```

Thanks,

Comment: The compiler identifies the result of the shift expressions to be `int`. You'd have to cast the result of the expressions to get rid of these warnings (i.e. `(uint16_t)(data << 8)`) but casting integers around isn't always a good idea unless one is quite sure about what is going on.

Comment: This `(uint16_t)data << 8` has `int` value, despite your cast, which was applied before the shift, so it is possible it can be truncated. I suggest `(uint16_t)(data << 8)`. Note that `data` is promoted to `int` before the shift.

Comment: Similarly with `crc = crc << 1` where the result of `crc << 1` is of type `int`. Suggest `crc = (uint16_t)(crc << 1)`.

Comment: @Weather Vane I've just been fooled these days, there are no default promotions :) Perhaps I should enable them but I prefer like this so I can truncate of shift. However, ok, it works, thanks.

Comment: @orfruit C11 says *"6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators . . . ¶3 The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand."*

Comment: I am on ISO C99 (-std=c99), I will check anuhow.

Comment: @orfruit C99 says the same, with same paragraph number.

Comment: @WeatherVane What does that mean for `val << 1`, when `val` is a `uint64_t`?. Does `val` also get promoted to `int`?

Comment: @Pablo there's no promotion in that case, if `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(uint64_t)` https://stackoverflow.com/q/46073295/995714

Comment: some have suggested `data << 8` but that would cause UB for some inputs on system with 16-bit `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a machine with `sizeof(int) == 4` and `CHAR_BITS == 8` (so `sizeof(int) > sizeof(uint16_t)`, the C standard stipulates that:

```
crc = crc ^ (uint16_t)data << 8;
```

undergoes the 'usual arithmetic conversions', and is treated more or less as though you'd written (the `8` is already an `int` so it doesn't get converted):

```
crc = (uint16_t)( ((int)crc) ^ (((int)((uint16_t)data)) << 8) );
```

And it is the assignment of the `int` result of the xor operator in the assignment to the `uint16_t` variable `crc` that triggers (accurately) the warning.

Similar remarks apply to each of the two other lines marked.

If you were working on a machine where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(uint16_t)`, you would not be getting the warnings in the first place.

[6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8):

> ¶1 Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result
>   types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a common real type for the operands
>   and result. For the specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
>   domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real type. Unless
>   explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of
>   the result, whose type domain is the type domain of the operands if they are the same,
>   and complex otherwise. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*:
>
> - *…floating point omitted…*
> - Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
>     following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
>   - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>   - Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>       integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
>       converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>   - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>       equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>       signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>       integer type.
>   - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent
>       all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then
>       the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
>       operand with signed integer type.
>   - Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>       corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

And [6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1) says:

> ¶2 … If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
>   bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned
>   int`. These are called the *integer promotions*.<sup>58)</sup> All other types are unchanged by the
>   integer promotions.
>
> <sup>58)</sup> The integer promotions are applied only: as part of the usual arithmetic conversions, to certain
>   argument expressions, to the operands of the unary `+`, `-`, and `~` operators, and to both operands of the
>   shift operators, as specified by their respective subclauses.

§6.3.1.1¶1 defines 'rank' in excruciating detail, but basically bigger types have a higher rank than smaller types (so `long` has a higher rank than `signed char`).

You can then find the specifications for the various operators:

[6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7):

> Each of the operands shall have integer type.
>
> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.

[6.5.11 Bitwise exclusive OR operator](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.11):

> Each of the operands shall have integer type.
>
> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.

[6.5.16 Assignment operators](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16)

> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand. An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment,<sup>111)</sup> but is not an lvalue. The type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion.
>
> <sup>111)</sup> The implementation is permitted to read the object to determine the value but is not required to, even
>   when the object has volatile-qualified type.

[6.5.16.1 Simple assignment](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1):

> In simple assignment (`=`), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the
>   assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left
>   operand.